# AspNetCore 3.1 Role Policies not working on views controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I've implemented Identity Scaffold on my project and Authentication works like a charm, I watched some tutorials of how to implement Roles with Identity and I'm having a hard time with the Role Policies labels on the controllers.

They all tell me I'm not authorized.

This is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => 
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI();           
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdminAccess", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));

            options.AddPolicy("ManagerAccess", policy =>
                policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                            context.User.IsInRole("Admin")
                            || context.User.IsInRole("Manager")));

            options.AddPolicy("UserAccess", policy =>
                policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                            context.User.IsInRole("Admin")
                            || context.User.IsInRole("Manager")
                            || context.User.IsInRole("User")));
        });

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>(i =>
            new EmailSender(
                Configuration["EmailSender:Host"],
                Configuration.GetValue<int>("EmailSender:Port"),
                Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EmailSender:EnableSSL"),
                Configuration["EmailSender:UserName"],
                Configuration["EmialSender:Password"]
            )
        );             
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();           
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Charts}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

I have a PolicyController.cs

```
public class PolicyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() => View();

    [Authorize(Policy = "UserAccess")]
    public IActionResult UserPage() => View();

    [Authorize(Policy = "ManagerAccess")]
    public IActionResult ManagerPage() => View();

    //[Authorize(Policy = "AdminAccess")]
    public IActionResult AdminPage()
    {
        // This returns FALSE
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            ViewBag.Message = "You Admin";
        ViewBag.Message = "No Admin";
        return View();
    }
}
```

I also have a view where I create roles and link them to a user, I even lookup at my DB and I see the RoleID with the UserID created on the aspnet-user-roles table but I'm not able to get on those test views with my created roles which are exactly typed as in the startup.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserRole(UpdateUserRoleViewModel vm)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.UserEmail);

    if (vm.Delete)
        await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, vm.Role);
    else
        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, vm.Role);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>   services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => 
>         options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
>             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
>     services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
>         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
>         .AddDefaultUI();
> ```

Perhaps the issue is related to the above code, from the code, it seems that you want to add custom user data to the AspNetUsers table. So, you will create a `ApplicationUser.cs` class and inheriting from `IdentityUser`, code like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    //custom user data.
    public string CustomTag { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the `Startup.ConfigureServices`, we could replace `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser`, and use the following code to configure the Identity:

```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                 .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                 .AddDefaultUI();

        //there is no need to add the following code:
        //services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //    .AddDefaultUI();
```

[**Note**] By using the above code, for all of the Scaffolding Identity razor pages, might be you also have to replace the `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser`.

If you don't want to add custom user data to the AspNetUsers table via the ApplicationUser class, try to remove the following code:

```
        //services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        //    .AddDefaultUI();
```

Besides, if still not working, please recheck the database, whether you are using the correct database, and check the user's roles from the `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles` table.